# File copy from external sdcard fails sometimes

Tags: external-sd, stock-android, file-transfer

I recently bought an sd card reader that can be connected via USB-C to a phone.

My phone recognized the SDCard inside that card reader and I can copy files - usually. However, it seems like when I try to copy more than 5 files it will definetly fail and I have to remove the reader, wait a few seconds and connect it again and try again.

I tried two filebrowsers. One came pre-installed with my phone ('Files') and Cx Fileexplorer. The latter seems to have less chance of failing but it will still fail eventually.

Neither of them will give me a proper error message aside from the list of files it couldn't copy.

The copied files were .jpg(5mb on average) and .CR2 ( Canon RAW files which are 22mb on average in size in my case).

Smartphone: Moto Z play, android 8.0.0 stock, not rooted. The SD card is 32 GB in size while my internal microSD is 64gb in size with 40gb free space.

Question would be: How to fix this?

Comment: Does the reader using the same card work without problems on a PC?

Comment: @Robert unknown as the usb-c cable is not detachable. I also haven't tried it on a different smartphone.

Comment: An SD-card reader with fixed USB-C cable? Can you please edit your question and add the details on the reader (brand, model)? Anyway PCs have USB-C ports, too. I strongly recommend you to test the reader somewhere else and try to use different SD-cards.

Comment: @Robert as I'm currently unable to test the reader on something else I tried a different card - same result - and another file explorer - Total Commander - which seems to work. I copied 200 files at 2.6 GB which worked without issues.

Comment: @Robert so, I copied files from the SD card via a SD Card reader connected to my computer which worked fine. I also tried a different SD Card with the reader connected to my phone, which resulted in the same problems: The default explorer and the Cx Fileexplorer abort after 4 to 8 files each time, while Total Commander works fine.

Comment: @Robert just as a follow up: I have tried the card and reader with different smartphones from friends (Android 8 and 8.1) and it worked flawlessly on each of  them. Meanwhile on my device it is no longer being recognized at all. As in the phone doesn't event recognize anymore that the reader was connected to the USB-C port.